# Send request to Kubernetes cluster using python script

Tags: python, api, kubernetes, deployment, google-cloud-platform

> I have deployed python API to google kubernetes cluster. I have get response using command line terminal as well as using my web browser . Now I want to send request using python script . Can anybody guide me how actually I connect my python script to google cloud kubernetes cluster and get my response to show in my python application .Thank you

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "deployed python API to google kubernetes cluster"?

Comment: I have deployed my pytho api to keubernetes using google cloud platform

Answer (score 2):

This is an example on how to use python requests library to send files to your endpoint.

```
import requests

url = "https://your.domain/end_point"
files = {'image': open('{file_path}', 'rb')}

response = requests.request("POST", url, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate both options  for me ?

Comment: The API documentation should be clear enough. https://googleapis.dev/python/container/latest/gapic/v1/api.html

It even has nice code examples.

Regarding option two there is this documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: can I send a request to my API and get back result using the code in the link?

Comment: read the setup and auth part also and after that yes following the api documentation you shuld be able. start with something easy like get clusters

Comment: hold up for a second. Maybe i misunderstood you. Do you need to manage your cluster using python API or are you talking about some other API you created yourself?

Comment: I have created a python API which take a picture as input and it result back me a prediction whether it is male or female. Now I deployed this Api to Google Kubernetes Engine . Now I want to design a program which make connection Google Kubernetes Engine and want to send a picture to get result from my api. I dont know how actually I make connection with my Api which is deployed Google Kubernetes Engine. Can you guide me about this

Comment: Ok so i understand now. You are able to send these pictures using command line correct?

Comment: I want to design a python script which send picture from local machine to my api which is deployed on  Google Kubernetes Engine and get back result to my local machine.

Comment: I understand. My question was about the current state. answer me theis - did sending and receiving pictures using your API work on your local machine?

Comment: My Api which is  is deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine work fine on Command line terminal (Using curl ) and on browser . Now actually I want to automate this process using python script.You get my point?

Comment: Yes i do get your point. All im doing is tryingt to clarify where the issues is. It never makes sense to deploy something to a cluster if the service does not work. 

If you are saying you can POST images to your service using curl from your machine then it should be working. 

Ill change my answer to show you a code example on how to send images using python requests.

Comment: I am not able to know how actually I can make connection ,send image and get back result using  python script

Comment: Look at the answer i wrote. under your initial question.

Comment: Thanks for First Answer

Comment: if it worked out you should mark the answer :) Thanks.

Comment: I have another question,when we deploy api on "Google Kubernetes Engine".Do we need credentials of "cluster-id",project id and other to setup the local "client" or we need only the external-ip to access the deployed api?

Comment: No, if you deployed your python API in the cluster and it has a public endpoint then NO you dont need any special credentials to send requests. Saying that you might need to implement somesort of authorization headers so only you could send the data. But in short NO you dont need anything other than the endpoint

Comment: what sort of header actually it is? can you share some resource

Comment: This is a bit complex to describe here but essentially you have to implement checking the token that is in the http post header and then use the token in the http header. RIght now for testing your picture upload this is not needed.

If you like you can read all about the request library here: https://2.python-requests.org//en/v1.0.0/user/quickstart/

Comment: After doing all of the above thing .......now i am facing following error can you guide me

Comment: ""HTTPConnectionPool(host='35.266.166.212', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))""

Comment: While i am sending request using python script ,it gives me above given error